# Rails - is "If @Project.save Else @Project.update" possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to use a form for both saving and updating some data. Basically if the project already exists it will update but if its new it will create a new entry

Is there a simple way to write the def create so that it will either save or update if the ProjectID parameter is nil? or present?

What i have now is

```
def create
@project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
if @project.save
  flash[:success] = "Project created!"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  flash[:success] = "Project not created!"
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

end

Could i put a call to an  update function in the else statement?

**Database Schema**

```
 create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "projectSubject"
t.string   "projectType"
t.string   "projectTitle"
t.string   "projectWorth"
t.date     "projectDueDate"
t.string   "projectDetails"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
```

end

Comment: Check this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by

Comment: thanks. Do i need to change the form in any way or is all the work done in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.where(id: params[:id]).first_or_create(project_params)
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:success] = "Project not created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

From [first_or_create documentation...](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)

> Specify the data you’re looking for. If it exists in the table, the first instance will be returned. If not, then create is called.

- `current_user.projects.where(id: params[:id])` ->  *Specify the data you’re looking for*
- `.first_or_create(project_params)` ->  *If it exists in the table, the first instance will be returned. If not, then create is called.*

Comment: The problem seems to be the id. Its just adding a new entry when i go to update.

Comment: Ive added the database schema in case it helps.

Comment: How are you sending the project id through the params? check on your terminal or you can do `puts params.inspect` inside `create` method.

Comment: you need to check the parameters passed to create method and perform `where(id: params[:id])` with the correct project id/attribute. Maybe its not `params[:id]`, maybe it's `params[:user][:project_id]`, I don't know. If you don't pass the correct value to `where` you always will create a new project.

Comment: it throws a 70227908419040 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4 error when i seem to get it correct. In the debugging at bottom of screen it has "id"=>"70227908419040" as a parameter. when i hit save it crashes with this error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `.update`. Save will do the right thing for new or existing records. You need to adjust your 2nd line to find or build a project though as what you have will always build.

That said, why wouldn't you have a `def update` method dedicated to updating and lave this method to just creating?

Comment: only way to answer that question is i have about 1 week experience with Rails so not too familiar. How would i call the update function instead of the create with the form submit button or is this done automatically somehow?